# sql code to print all the mondays of the year 2012

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

```
2012
     January
            2/1/2012
            9/1/2012
            16/1/2012
            23/1/2012
            30/1/2012
     February
            6/2/2012
                .
                .
                .
                .
```

and so on till decemeber.

the dates mentioned are mondays..How do i get the output in this format?? please help

Answer (score 2):

One option

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select next_day(trunc(sysdate,'YYYY') + 7*(level-1), 'MON' )
  2    from dual
  3* connect by level <= 53
SQL> /

NEXT_DAY(
---------
02-JAN-12
09-JAN-12
16-JAN-12
23-JAN-12
30-JAN-12
06-FEB-12
13-FEB-12
20-FEB-12
27-FEB-12
05-MAR-12
12-MAR-12
<<snip>>
03-DEC-12
10-DEC-12
17-DEC-12
24-DEC-12
31-DEC-12

53 rows selected.
```

Comment: thanks jusitn...but how do i print the year and month with indentation

Comment: @BharathRV - Are you trying to return 3 columns of data?  Or are you trying to return one column of data (`VARCHAR2` presumably) that contains formatted strings?  Returning a single column that is either a string representing a year, a string representing a month, or a string representing a date and that contains additional formatting would be rather unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
select distinct next_day(to_date('01-01-2012','mm-dd-yyyy')-1+level,'Monday') All_MON from dual 
connect by level <= floor(to_date('12-31-2011','mm-dd-yyyy') - to_date('01-01-2011','mm-dd-yyyy'))
order by All_MON;
```

Output:

01/02/2012 MONDAY
01/09/2012 MONDAY
01/16/2012 MONDAY
01/23/2012 MONDAY
01/30/2012 MONDAY
02/06/2012 MONDAY
02/13/2012 MONDAY
02/20/2012 MONDAY
02/27/2012 MONDAY
03/05/2012 MONDAY
03/12/2012 MONDAY
03/19/2012 MONDAY
03/26/2012 MONDAY
04/02/2012 MONDAY
04/09/2012 MONDAY
04/16/2012 MONDAY
04/23/2012 MONDAY
04/30/2012 MONDAY
05/07/2012 MONDAY
05/14/2012 MONDAY
05/21/2012 MONDAY
05/28/2012 MONDAY
06/04/2012 MONDAY
06/11/2012 MONDAY
06/18/2012 MONDAY
06/25/2012 MONDAY
07/02/2012 MONDAY
07/09/2012 MONDAY
07/16/2012 MONDAY
07/23/2012 MONDAY
07/30/2012 MONDAY
08/06/2012 MONDAY
08/13/2012 MONDAY
08/20/2012 MONDAY
08/27/2012 MONDAY
09/03/2012 MONDAY
09/10/2012 MONDAY
09/17/2012 MONDAY
09/24/2012 MONDAY
10/01/2012 MONDAY
10/08/2012 MONDAY
10/15/2012 MONDAY
10/22/2012 MONDAY
10/29/2012 MONDAY
11/05/2012 MONDAY
11/12/2012 MONDAY
11/19/2012 MONDAY
11/26/2012 MONDAY
12/03/2012 MONDAY
12/10/2012 MONDAY
12/17/2012 MONDAY
12/24/2012 MONDAY
12/31/2012 MONDAY